# How to assign default value to a date in aggregate function?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
select isnull(min(date_tested),'01-01-2010') from test_date where date_tested>=@startdate and enddate<=@enddate
```

I get this output sometimes-

```
datetested
__________
```

I want -

```
datetested
01-01-2010
```

So this does not work...i mean in cases where the date is not there it returns blank..i want to return a default value anytime it returns i guess blank....as I guess date_tested is not null otherwise it would have asigned value to it..how can i assign default value to it in cases where it is null ?

Comment: what exactly is not working?, is this a function?, what do you mean with default value to it?

Comment: updated my question hopefully makes little more sense.

Comment: @Misnomer: please post a sample of your data and a desired recordset.

Comment: if date_tested is not null, and it returns blank, then I assume that is column of datatype CHAR. Is that correct?. Do you want the default value to be assign on the table or on the result of your query?

Comment: I want a default value assigned to query...i have added sample o/p

Comment: I wonder where you get the colunname from. You didn't add a name to the expression isnull(min(date_tested),'01-01-2010') and for me the result on sql-2005 shows a blank column name

Comment: @Mis won't delete as many people tried to help you.  You should provide an answer which explains what happened, then accept it in a couple days.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select coalesce(date_tested,'01-01-2010') from test_date group by date_tested
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

select min(isnull(date_tested,'01-01-2010')) from test_date group by date_tested

Using isnull and case statments inside of aggregates can get you a lot of power

Answer (score 0):

Why do you group by the column which is used in aggregate function? If there are X values that satisfy condition in `WHERE`, you will get X rows. But if it is really what you want, you can use

```
SELECT 
ISNULL((SELECT MIN(date_tested) 
FROM test_date 
WHERE date_tested>=@startdate and enddate<=@enddate  
group by date_tested),'01-01-2010') as [datetested];
```

Comment: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Surely, because grouping by the same column causes to return the same recordset as without aggregate and group by.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't understand if you want the MIN date_tested or you want all posible values of date_tested, cause you are using MIN on date_tested and you are GROUPING BY date_tested. If you want the MIN value then you can do the following:

```
SELECT MIN(ISNULL(date_tested,'01-01-2010'))
FROM test_date
WHERE date_tested>=@startdate and enddate<=@enddate
```

you have to be careful with that, cause you are assigning a value to date_tested if it was null. If you want all posible values for date_tested, then you can do this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(date_tested,'01-01-2010')
FROM test_date
WHERE date_tested>=@startdate and enddate<=@enddate 
GROUP BY ISNULL(date_tested,'01-01-2010')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using your start date parameter as a default like this...

```
select isnull(min(date_tested),@startdate)
from test_date 
where date_tested>=@startdate 
and enddate<=@enddate
```